# selecting all non-empty sub-rectangle in a 2D list

Tags: python, list, sublist

Task: Print all non-empty sub-rectangle in a 2D list, the time limit is 1 sec.

I have tried in python. But, I'm unable to get efficient. It took more than one second for execution.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
x = 3
y = 3
for i in range(x):
    a.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
total = []
for h in range(1,x+1):
    for k in range(1,y+1):
        temp = []
        for p in range(x):
            for d in range(y):
                for i in range(p,h):
                    for j in range(d,k):
                        temp.append(a[i][j])
                if len(temp)==0:
                    pass
                else:
                    total.append(temp)
                    temp = []
 print(total)
 print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

code execution shouldn't take more than one second. Is there is any other way reducing loops that reduce execution time?

Comment: Can you please supply some sample data

Comment: With the most trivial of input, 4\n4\n4\n, this runs for me in well under a millisecond. - must depend in the input if yours is so much slower.  So what does your input look like?  What am I supposed to enter when prompted?

Comment: I printed time using the time module, it showed me some time greater than13 seconds

Comment: Did it seem to take 13 seconds?  You aren't including the input time, are you?  What is your input?

Comment: see the code again I included time module

Comment: The start time is set before reading the input.  So the total time includes the time taken to provide and read the input.  You want to start the timer after the for loop that reads the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for input from the user, and you're timing the collection of that input.  So the time is meaningless...the user can take an arbitrary amount of time to enter data.  Why would you want to time that?  You need to make the user enter 3 numbers in under 1 second?

Also, the entered data is never used.  It is appended onto the array 'a', but only the first three entries in that array, which were there before the input is added, are used in the calculations.  So you might as well take the two lines that collect user input out of the code.  If you do this, you get:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
x = 3
y = 3
total = []
for h in range(1,x+1):
    for k in range(1,y+1):
        temp = []
        for p in range(x):
            for d in range(y):
                for i in range(p,h):
                    for j in range(d,k):
                        temp.append(a[i][j])
                if len(temp)==0:
                    pass
                else:
                    total.append(temp)
                    temp = []
print(total)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And my result from running this is:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], [1, 4], [4], [1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 5], [4, 5], [5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 5, 6], [3, 6], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6], [6], [1, 4, 7], [4, 7], [7], [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8], [2, 5, 8], [4, 5, 7, 8], [5, 8], [7, 8], [8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9], [3, 6, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6, 8, 9], [6, 9], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9], [9]]
--- 0.00019288063049316406 seconds ---
```

so about 1/5th of a millisecond

Maybe you have a slower computer than mine?  It would have to be more than 5000 times slower for this to take 1 second to run.

If you want to take input from the user even though you don't do anything with it, then sample your start time after the user has entered the data.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about time taking by entering input :D.

Comment: Actually, this is a challenge in A2 Online Judge, It is showing that execution time is 1.01. It isn't accepting my code as time exceeds. Is there any way to reduce the execution time.

Comment: Maybe.  One thing is that a good part of the execution time of this is the time the print statement takes to run.  Try taking your end time sample before you do the print.  I don't know if that helps.  Otherwise, I don't really understand what this is doing and I don't have the time to understand it.  It sure seems like an awful many embedded loops.  I would think there would be some optimization that could be done.

Comment: when I submitted code, it showed execution time as 1.01 seconds